# "От 6 лет и старше" — можно так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, плеоназм

Часто вижу подобные словосочетания, и всегда мне это казалось ошибкой. Возможно, я ошибаюсь: это стало чем-то типа оборота и так всё-таки нормально говорить?

Мне казалось, что можно говорить только: *для детей от шести лет* или *для детей старше шести лет.*

Answer (score 2):

Артём, это, конечно, плеоназм, Вы правы, корректно говорить *для детей от шести лет или для детей старше шести лет.*

К сожалению, среди плеоназмов есть штампы, устойчивые сочетания, употребляемые неосознанно, по устоявшейся традиции: *лично я, в мае месяце*. По-моему, употребление *“от 6 лет и старше”* стало таким же штампом.

Близки к штампам и такие, как: основной лейтмотив, пережиток прошлого, прейскурант цен, информационное сообщение, букет цветов, главная суть, другая альтернатива, интерактивное взаимодействие, истинная правда, необычный феномен, ответная реакция, отступать назад, установленный факт, наиболее оптимальный, хронометраж времени, первая премьера, смешивать вместе.

Человек, считающий себя грамотным, употреблять их не будет, но мы должны быть снисходительными к тем, кто допускает в своей бытовой речи такие ошибки. А вот то, что такие ошибки мы видим и в речи телеведущих и публичных уважаемых людей — это уже хуже, "за Отечество обидно"...

Comment: Очень интересный ответ, но с некоторыми из ваших примеров я бы поспорил (можно бы вынести такую тему как отдельную: истинный и ложный плеоназм). "Установленный факт" - факты существуют объективно, незвисимо от нашего знания, а установленные факты - это факты, о существовании которых нам стало известно. "Истинная правда" (в отличие от правды "ложной") - это выражение родилось в ответ на реалии нашей жизни.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Людмила, за ответ и поддержку!

Comment: Только я считал, что "май месяц" говорят просто для красоты. Так звучит поэтичнее. Вы уверены, что такое понимание неправильное?

Comment: В словаре есть: ***букет полевых цветов***.

Comment: @Серж, Если просто букет, то он из цветов. А если нужно уточнить, что из полевых, то приходится добавить еще два слова. Это нормально.

Comment: *Это нормально.* Мне тоже так кажется на первый взляд.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сказал: **"для детей шести лет и старше"**. Здесь все однозначно понятно.

"Для детей старше шести лет" — формально не включает детей 6 лет.

"Для детей от шести лет" — формально допускает два толкования (от шести и старше или от шести и младше).

"Для детей от шести лет и старше" (в противоположность "от шести лет и младше") - здесь лишнее "от" ничего не добавляет по сравнению с моим вариантом. Вариант допустимый, на мой взгляд, но стилистически неудачный, плеоназм.

Comment: *от шести и старше или от шести и младше* Хм, разве кто-то "вниз" считает в нашем мире? И подход у Вас какой-то формальный. "Не включает детей шести лет" обязательно должно означать "шести или шести с чем-то", т. е. от шести до семи? По-моему, можно просто считать, что раз исполнилось шесть, ты уже попадаешь в категорию "старше шести". Хотя да, "от шести" в любом случае звучит понятнее, согласен. И вниз будет считать только дурак или привередливый человек.)))

Comment: Я и не скрывал, что подход формальный (с учетом наличия  дураков и юристов:))) Я тоже считаю, что в повседневной жизни можно говорить "от  шести".  А вот "старше шести" реально может ввести в заблуждение (что делать с теми, кому не исполнилось семь лет)

Comment: *с учетом наличия дураков и юристов* ))))))))